# And yet we see that Sauron can torture and destroy the very hills

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

What did Galdor refer to in the Council of Elrond when said

> And yet we see that Sauron can torture and destroy the very hills.

Do we have a description of such an event somewhere?

Comment: (Inner) Earth Works (AKA civil engineering - though if it involves 'torture' I suppose that's uncivil engineering).

Comment: Apparently Sauron first became recognized as evil for smashing the creations of small children who played Minecraft.

Answer (score 6):

From context, this statement occurs during the Council of Elrond and following on from the stories of Elrond, Boromir, Bilbo, Frodo, Gandalf and with interjections from others.

It seems evident that it must be a reference to something in one of those stories, and the most probable event is Sauron's invasion and ruin of Eriador in the Second Age, during which he killed Celebrimbor and siezed the Rings of Power.

This is referred to in the description of Elrond's story:

> ... many eyes were turned to Elrond in fear and wonder as he told of the
>   Elven-smiths of Eregion and their friendship with Moria, and their eagerness for knowledge, by which Sauron ensnared them. For in that time he was not yet evil to behold, and they received his aid and grew mighty in craft, whereas he learned all their secrets, and betrayed them, and forged secretly in the Mountain of Fire the One Ring to be their master. But Celebrimbor was aware of him, and hid the Three which he had made; and **there was war, and the land was laid waste**, and the gate of Moria was shut.

And is covered in more detail in the Galadriel and Celeborn material in Unfinished Tales:

> When Sauron learned of the repentance and revolt of Celebrimbor his disguise fell and his wrath was revealed; and gathering a great force he moved over Calenardhon (Rohan) to the invasion of Eriador in the year 1695 ..... At last **the attackers broke into Eregion with ruin and devastation** ..... But now Sauron attempted to gain the mastery of Eriador: Lórinand could wait. But as **he ravaged the lands** ..... he called in therefore his scattered forces and **marched west towards the land of Gil-galad, ravaging as he went**.

And the aftermath, after the Numenoreans ("the great armament of Tar-Minastir") intervened:

> Eriador was cleared of the enemy, but **lay largely in ruins**.

Aside from Rivendell (which was besieged), the major Elven stronghold - "the land of Gil-galad" - which Sauron was marching toward, was Lindon where the Grey Havens are, and Galdor is of course an Elf of the Havens.

Sauron's ability to "torture and destroy the very hills" is therefore most probably a reference to the ruin of Eriador in the Second Age.

Answer (score 4):

Good answers are here already, but there's a few more...

### The Brown Lands

These are perhaps the clearest example of the destruction Sauron can wreak. We saw them first in *Fellowship*:

> The trees thinned and then failed altogether.  On the eastern bank to their left they saw long formless slopes stretching up and away towards the sky; brown and withered they looked, as if fire had passed over them, leaving no living blade of green: an unfriendly waste without even a broken tree or a bold stone to relieve the emptiness. They had come to the Brown Lands that lay, vast and desolate, between Southern Mirkwood and the hills of the Emyn Muil. What pestilence or war or evil deed of the Enemy had so blasted all that region even Aragorn could not tell.

Maybe Aragorn couldn't, but Treebeard could. He recalls that it was once a region rather like the Shire, before Sauron came, in *Two Towers*:

> After the Darkness was overthrown the land of the Entwive blossomed richly, and their fields were full of corn. Many men learned the crafts of the Entwives and honoured them greatly; but we were only a legend to them, a secret in the heart of the forest. Yet here we still are, while all the gardens of the Entwives are wasted: Men call them the Brown Lands now.
>
> ...
>
> We crossed over Anduin and came to their land; but we found a desert: It was all burned and uprooted, for war had passed over it...if Sauron of old destroyed the gardens, the Enemy today seems likely to wither all the woods.

### The Desolation before Mordor

> Frodo looked round in horror. Dreadful as the Dead Marshes had been...more loathsome far was the country that the crawling day now slowly unveiled to his shrinking eyes...Here neither spring nor summer would ever come again. Here nothing lived, not even the leprous growths that feed on rottenness. The gasping pools were choked with ash and crawling muds, sickly white and grey, as if the mountains had vomited the filth of their entrails upon the lands about. High mounds of crushed and powdered rock, great cones of earth fire-blasted and poison-stained, stood like an obscene graveyard in endless rows, slowly revealed in the reluctant light.
>
> They had come to the desolation that lay before Mordor: the lasting monument to he dark labour of its slaves that should endure when all their purposes were made void; a land defiled, diseased beyond all healing.

### The Dead Marshes...perhaps

It's not clear whether the land here was twisted by Sauron, or if the death of so many men and elves corrupted the land without his help.

### Mordor itself...probably

Mordor is the clearest example of a destroyed and ruined land. Nothing grew there except twisted brambles, and no water ran. Of course, this was mostly due to the regular action of Mount Doom, but Mount Doom itself was apparently driven by Sauron's will; certainly it was his return to Mordor that ignited it again after centuries of slumber, and he used it to signal his attacks against Gondor. If Sauron has that power, then he certainly can "torture and destroy the very hills".

Comment: This is interesting. I took Galdor's word as to mean something akin to Melkor creating the Misty Mountains on a smaller scale.

Comment: If you look at the progression, it makes sense - at first Melkor was so powerful he created entire mountain ranges just to slow his enemies down; after his defeat, he was limited to building up Thangorodrim, an impressive feat, to be sure, but not to compare to building the Misty Mountains; then Sauron only managed a single volcano; then Saruman tried to spoil the Shire. Evil always destroys as best it can.

Answer (score 1):

The only example I can think of is the description of the hills about the Black Gate (Morannon) when Frodo and Sam first see it.

> Across the mouth of the pass, from cliff to cliff, the Dark
>   Lord had built a rampart of stone. In it there was a single gate
>   of iron, and upon its battlement sentinels paced unceasingly.
>   Beneath the hills on either side the rock was bored into a
>   hundred caves and maggot-holes; there a host of orcs lurked,
>   ready at a signal to issue forth like black ants going to war.
>
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* Book Four, Chapter 3: *The Black Gate is Closed*</sub>

It isn't much, but I suppose that the boring of all those "maggot-holes" could be considered torture.

Answer (score 1):

To me this sounds like he's talking about how Sauron exploits/"tortures" everything, even the ground (i.e. orcs creating mines to increase the size of his army) on an industrial/strip mining level. After all you could compare (deep) mining to torturing, where you poke the victim till you get something out of it (ore in this case).

The humans of Middle Earth are more on a Middle Ages level, so I'd assume their mines are typically rather small and concentrated, with little to no significant (visual) impact on their actual surroundings.

Comment: Well, mine size wise there's Erebor and Moria.

Comment: @chx True, although I'm not sure how well known their extends, appearance etc. are.

Answer (score 1):

I think he could be referencing the [Mirkwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirkwood); two forests that fell under the power of Morgoth and Sauron (as the Necromancer in the Hobbit); because anyone can destroy the land via war or strip mining, but not everyone can corrupt and destroy the very land using dark magic.

These forests used to be lush and green but then became black and corrupted by Morgath and Sauron.

Morgoth corrupted the highlands of Dorthonion in the first Age and Sauron corrupted Greenwood the Great in the Third Age.

After Sauron's defeat, Galadriel cleansed the Mirkwood (formally called Greenwood the Great) and it was renamed again as the Wood of Greenleaves.

Comment: I think you mean Morgoth rather than Morgath, but the darkening of Greenwood the Great didn't happen until after Morgoth had been defeated and expelled from Middle-earth.

Comment: @Blackwood - that was a typo on my part and I added more info; Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia, Sauron had  direct control of Mount Doom 
-"Orodruin is more than just an ordinary volcano; it responds to Sauron's commands and his presence, lapsing into dormancy when he is away from Mordor and becoming active again when he returns".
Also Sauron originally was a Maia of The Vala Aule who created The Dwarves & he remained mighty in that lore.

Comment: Great answer, however u should attribute your sources :)